# How to write WI (TestCase) from TFS 2010 to 2013?

Tags: tfs, migration, testcase

Good day!

I try to migrate test cases from TFS 2010 to 2013 version.

So, i can get WorkItem from TFS 2010, but dont know how to set it to 2013?

Please,tell me how to write existing WI (TestCases) into TFS 2013.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Test Cases from MTM or TFS Web Access (or via the TFS API).

If you need to do a bulk migration you can use tcmimport tool (google it), to migrate data via Excel, or one of the several TFS Migration Tools (that often cost money).